# How to GET current page number of PDF document in C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I open a PDF file like this: ...

```
using System. Diagnostics; 
public Form1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
            axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"D:\myBook.pdf"); 
            axAcroPDF1.Show(); 
        }
```

But when I go to another page and want to see its number, I can't find method Get or something similar. How can I read the number of page, which is opened at the moment???

Comment: Do you have the Acrobat SDK installed? You cannot get current page number via AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF if you have only Acrobat Reader installed.

Answer (score 0):

How can you get the page number:

```
Dim pdfPage As Acrobat.CAcroPDPage
Set pdfPage = pdfPageView.GetPage
lPage = pdfPage.GetNumber
```